# Flipping matrix columns

Tags: r

I have a matrix:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    5    9   13   17
[2,]    2    6   10   14   18
[3,]    3    7   11   15   19
[4,]    4    8   12   16   20
```

I want to flip it so that the last column will be the firs and the first will be the last. 
I know how to do it with a loop but is there any other quicker way to do this, e.g. with a function.

Here is the code that creates the matrix:

```
mat=matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20), ncol=5)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use reverse sequencing from last column index to the first one to do the flipping

```
mat[,ncol(mat):1]
```

It can be wrapped into a function

```
revflip <- function(matr) {
          matr[, ncol(matr):1, drop = FALSE]
  }

revflip(mat)
```